# Haskell - list traversing

Tags: list, if-statement, haskell, traversal

I want to traverse list of lists and check every element if its equal a char or not. How can I do this? I get an error even when I write if statement. I would be glad if you can help.

example list that I want to traverse:

```
maze = [ ['E','#','#','#'],
       [' ','#',' ',' '],
       [' ',' ',' ',' '],
       ['#','#','#','S'] ]
```

If statement:

```
checkElement :: Char -> Bool
checkElement x = if x == '#'
  then False
  else True
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When your question involves an error of some sort, it's usually a good idea to post the full text of that error, so that people trying to answer your question don't have to guess. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: voting to close due to lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with the `map` function:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

When you want to map over a nested list, you can use `(map . map) :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]`:

```hs
λ (map . map) checkElement mazes
[ [ False, True , True , True  ]
, [ False, True , False, False ]
, [ False, False, False, False ]
, [ True , True , True , False ] ]
```

It's also worth noting that `if x then False else True` can be replaced with `not x`:

```hs
checkElement :: Char -> Bool
checkElement x = not $ x == '#'
```

Comment: ...and `not $ x == y` with `x /= y`, and, more controversially, `\x -> x /= y` with `(/= y)`, at which point it's short enough that it's probably not even worth defining as a separate function.

Comment: @DanielWagner True enough. I just want to hammer on the point that `if ... then True else False` and `if ... then False else True` are always needlessly complicated, which seems to be a common issue with people who are new to Haskell (even it seems if they're not new to programming).